# How to avoid displaying parameters in the URL when doing an $http GET with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, parameters

I have this very simple login, but due to our backend structure, I have to do my login with $http GET request with angularjs.

However, I dont want usernames and passwords to be seen in the URL.

so I am curious what can I do to solve this problem? any help would be appreciated.

here is my LoginController.js

```
self.login = function() {

    if (self.username == '' || self.password == '') {

        alert("Please Check your credentials");
    } else {
        LoginService.login(self.username, self.password).then(function (resp) {
            //console.log(resp);
                LoginService.setCredentials(self.username,self.password);
                $state.go('dashboard');
        })
    }

}
```

and here is LoginService.js

```
    var loginSuccess = function (response) {
        //console.log(response.data);
        //console.log(response.data.keyId);

        $rootScope.keyId = response.data.keyId;
        $cookies.put('keyId',$rootScope.keyId);

        self.isLoggedIn = true;
        //$state.go('dashboard');

        return response.data;

    };

    return {

        login: function (username, password) {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'https://URLHERE/ApplicationKeys/'+username+'Key/?userid='+username+'&password='+password,
                headers: {'ACCEPT':'application/json'}
            }).then(loginSuccess,loginFailure);
        },
        isLoggedIn: function () {
            return self.isLoggedIn;
        },
```

Comment: Why are you doing get for something that has username and password.  POST is the proper method for this.  You do not want someone to able to just follow a link that does this.

Comment: Well, I am aware of that, but this is not something that I can change, I need to GET the application key and there is no POST service for that so they told me to use get and they cannot change this for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you control the server that this is talking to, you should modify it to be a POST.  Gets are for getting information, not updating information

Also you can pass a data object instead of having it as part of the url.

```
return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://URLHERE/ApplicationKeys/'+username+'Key/',
            headers: {'ACCEPT':'application/json'},
            data: {userid: username, password: password}
        }).then(loginSuccess,loginFailure);
```

Comment: did you mean passing the data object to "login: function (username, password)" here?

Comment: Using the above as the $http method call in your code example.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer my own. Obviously, when you are using `<form></form>` tags in the html, that sticks all the information to the URL in the browser. Everything went away when I removed the `<form>` tag in the html page.